# Visual code + Python: how to quick fix all?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-import

In my Python code, I have a lot of problems that I can solve by applying "quick fix" with Pylance (for example, Add import ... on the picture below).
How to apply quick fix on all of them, rather than one by one?
[image: quick fix]

Answer (score 1):

Pylance is an extension for vscode. This means that resolving errors must be done in the problems tab. I would recommend switching to an IDE like PyCharm for easier error resolution.

Answer (score 1):

At present, Pylance in VSCode does not support batch processing "quick fix".

[Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) mainly provides language services and code IntelliSense functions for Python in VSCode.

Thank you for posting this suggestion here, and we have submitted it, let us look forward to the realization of this feature.

Github link: [Is it possible to process Pylance's "quick fix" in batches, or to process the same type together?](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/763)

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. I am glad you are interested in this feature and I will follow the issue.